# How to validate data in an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call data from a PHP file where it takes the data entered and tells if it is validated or not. How do you do this in the javascript file using an AJAX call?

```
$("#PersonForm").submit(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'backend.php', type: 'post', data: { act:'validate'},
        dataType: 'json',
       function(result) {
            if($validateData==1){
                $('#success').html('validated');
            }
            else{
                $('#errors').html('Not Correct');
            }
        }

        //});

    });
    return false;

 });
```

Here is the PHP file

```
<?php
if ($_REQUEST['act'] == 'validate')
{
  $validateData = array();

  if (preg_match("/^[A-Za-z]{3,20}$/",$_REQUEST['name'])) $validateData['name'] = 1;
  else $validateData['name'] = 0;

  if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{10}$/",$_REQUEST['phone'])) $validateData['phone'] = 1;
  else $validateData['phone'] = 0;

  if (preg_match("/^[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]$/",
                              $_REQUEST['postal'])) $validateData['postal'] = 1;
  else $validateData['postal'] = 0;

  if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{3} [A-Za-z]{3,10} Street$/",
                              $_REQUEST['address'])) $validateData['address'] = 1;
  else $validateData['address'] = 0;

  echo json_encode($validateData);
}
else echo "Should not happen";

?>
```

HTML file:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Form Validation</h1>

<form id="PersonForm">

Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name"> <br>

Postal Code: <input type="text" id="postal" name="postal"> <br>

Phone Number: <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"> <br>

Address: <input type="text" id="address" name="address"> <br>

<input id="sub" type="submit">

</form>

<a href="frontend.html">Refresh</a> 
<a id="InsertDefault" href="">Insert Default Data</a> 
<br>

<ul id="errors"></ul>
<p id="success"></p>

</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `$validateData==1`?

Comment: I set $validateData to 1 in the php file when the data is valid

Comment: PHP variables aren't visible in Javascript. The response is in `result`.

Comment: Ohhh that makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're not sending the any of the inputs in your `data:` parameter. So `$_REQUEST['name']`, `$_REQUEST['phone']`, etc. won't exist.

Second, you can't access PHP variables in Javascript. The JSON that the PHP echoes at the end will be decoded into the `result` variable in the `success:` callback function.

Third, your syntax is wrong, the callback function needs to be in the `success:` option.

So it should be:

```
$("#PersonForm").submit(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'backend.php', 
        type: 'post', 
        data: 'act=validate&' + $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            if(result.name && result.phone && result.post && result.address){
                $('#success').html('validated');
            }
            else{
                $('#errors').html('Not Correct');
            }
        }    
    });
    return false;
 });
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that you could not access PHP variables

Comment: PHP runs on the server, Javascript runs on the client.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the success and error callbacks so that you are waiting for the promise from the ajax call to come back. I am assuming you are trying to figure out how to get to the data that comes back. If you need further assistance with then validating the real data, I can help with that as well.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'backend.php', type: 'post', data: { act:'validate'},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if($validateData==1){
            $('#success').html('validated');
        }
        else{
            $('#errors').html('Not Correct');
        }
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        // Error occurred calling API
    }
});
```

Comment: How does adding the `error:` callback help? There's still nothing that sets `$validateData` in the Javascript.

Comment: The question was a little vague, i didn't know if he was having trouble getting the data back or the steps there after.  result is the Response. I dont know what he is expecting validateData to be? Please share more details.

Comment: It's not my question. If you don't understand the question, you should ask him to clarify in a comment.